# EclipseFP auto-completion (intellisense) is missing items

Tags: haskell, eclipse-fp

I'm trying using Eclipse with the EclipseFP plugin to develop a simple application in Haskell using [Fay](http://fay-lang.org).

For some reason Fay modules are not showing up in the IDE's autocompletion. For example, if I type `import.` and hit ctrl-space a list of modules appears but none of the `Language.Fay.*` modules are amongst them.

`fay` is listed in the `build-depends` section of my project's `.cabal` file, and the source compiles absolutely fine with GHC.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on my machine (famous words, I know). 
This functionality is provided by scion-browser, so if you open the Haskell Browser perspective, you should see fay appear in the Packages view, and clicking on it shows you the packages. If you see nothing in the Packages view, scion-browser is not working or not installed, check the path is correct in the preferences. If you see other packages but not fay, have you restarted EclipseFP? I think scion-browser should update automatically when you install new packages, but maybe something went wrong.
Bottom line: it should work, but maybe a configuration issue in EclipseFP is the culprit.